# driver.close() method not working in docker container for latest image of selenium/node-firefox-debug

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, firefox, containers

driver.close() method not working in docker container for latest image of selenium/node-firefox-debug

selenium/node-firefox-debug: Grid Node with Firefox installed and runs a VNC server, needs to be connected to a Grid Hub

There is no problem with execution just driver.close() is giving issues

below is how initiated forefox

```
public class Docker_class_firefox {
static RemoteWebDriver driver;
@Test
public void test() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Hello FireFox");
    DesiredCapabilities cmp = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cmp.setPlatform(Platform.LINUX);
    cmp.setBrowserName(BrowserType.FIREFOX);
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),cmp);
    driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue. `webDriverThreadLocal.get().quit()` made node available again.